# Getting Command cannot be null even if condition is false in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have been working on this for hours and can't seem to identify what I am doing wrong. Appreciate if anyone can help on this.

**Issue:**

I have an ECS CFT template where I am supposed to update the health check command within the Container Definition. If the parameter for the health check command is available then I should include it or pass aws no value. Here is the reference from my template. However, after running this I am getting

> Invalid request provided: Create TaskDefinition: You must specify a health check command for your container.

I want the param to be optional. So I didn't pass the parameter while updating the stack.

Parameters:

```json
    "ContainerHealthCheckCommand": {
      "Description": "Health check command of the container"
      "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
      "Default": ""
     }
```

Conditions:

```json
    "hasContainerHealthCheckCommand": {
       "Fn::Not": [{ "Fn::Equals": [{"Fn::Select": ["0", {"Ref": "ContainerHealthCheckCommand"}, ""]}]} 
    }
```

Within My Resource ContainerDefinition

```json
"HealthCheck": {"Fn::If": [
  "hasContainerHealthCheckCommand", {
    "Command": {"Ref":"ContainerHealthCheckCommand"}
   },
   {"Ref": "AWS::NoValue"}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an unrelated error. The above code worked well after that.